# How can i get slug for page using url helper in codeigniter for checking active page

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, slug

I am following the tuts+ course for developing CMS for news portal. I am getting instance using codeigniter super object.I have already included url helper in autoload then also i can not fetch the slug for the page. I am checking uri with the slug name of the item so that i can find the active page.

```
$CI =& get_instance();//for getting instance
$slug_name=$CI->uri->segment(1);
```

Here $CI will get all the instances but the $active will have NULL value 
`$active=$CI->uri->segment(1)==$item['slug']?TRUE:FALSE;`
please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this code in a library or a controller? Which version of Codeigniter are you using?

Comment: @KevinP its in the helper folder version 3.1.2 `function get_menu($array,$child=false){
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $str='';
    if (count($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            $active=$CI->uri->segment(1)==$item['slug']?TRUE:FALSE;
            if (isset($item['children'])&& count($item['children'])) {
                $str.=$active?'<li class="dropdown active">':'<li class="dropdown">';
//list code here
            }else{
                $str.=$active?'<li class="active">':'<li>';
            } 
        }
    }
    return $str;
}`